# JUnit expected: but was: Error - Understanding JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I am new to JUnit and testing and am seriously at my wits end with this error:
`expected:<null> but was: expected:<null> but was:<Order ID: 1, Customer ID: 1, Customer Name: jordan harrison, Item ID: 1, Item Name: Call of Duty, Quantity: 0, Total Cost: 0.0>`

I have no idea why the below test does not work whatsoever. I have looked at other similar questions but they don't help my understanding of the tests at all and left me at a complete loss for how to fix this.

Here's the test:

```java
public class OrderDAOTest {
    
    private final OrderDAO DAO = new OrderDAO();

@Before
    public void setup() {
        DBUtils.connect();
        DBUtils.getInstance().init("src/test/resources/sql-schema.sql", "src/test/resources/sql-data.sql");
    }

@Test
    public void testRead() {
        
        Long oId = 1L;
        Long iId = 1L;
        Long cId = 1L;
        String iName = "Call of Duty";
        double iCost = 25.99;
        Item item = new Item(iId, iName, iCost);
        Customer customer = new Customer(cId);
        CustomerDAO custDao = new CustomerDAO();
        customer = custDao.read(customer.getCustomerId());
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderId(1L);
        order.setItem(item);
        order.setCustomer(customer);
        System.out.println(order);
        
        assertEquals(DAO.read(order.getOrderId()), order);
    }
```

This is the `read()` method with the `orderItemsFromResultSet()` method that it returns in the OrderDAO Class:

```java
public Order orderItemsFromResultSet(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        Long orderId = rs.getLong("fk_order_id");
        Long itemId = rs.getLong("item_id");
        String itemName = rs.getString("item_name");
        double itemCost = rs.getDouble("item_cost");
        Item item = new Item(itemId, itemName, itemCost);
        Order order = new Order(item, orderId);
        return order;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Order read(Long id) {
        try (Connection connection = DBUtils.getInstance().getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM order_items LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.item_id = order_items.fk_item_id WHERE fk_order_id = ?");) {
            statement.setLong(1, id);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();) {
                resultSet.next();
                return orderItemsFromResultSet(resultSet);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug(e);
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I just don't understand it and need help with understanding testing altogether.

Comment: What is DAO? It is certain, that `DAO.read` returns null, as the first parameter of `assertEquals` is the expected, which is `null`

Comment: Determined at top of Class 
`public class OrderDAOTest { private final OrderDAO DAO = new OrderDAO();` - Added that info to question

Comment: Can you add a break point in DAO function and check whether the db call is succeeding or you are getting an exception

Comment: So it turns out I was getting an error but I have since fixed that, (it was the toString() method causing issues), but the test still fails. I will try doing break points and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You are catching all exceptions and then just returning `null`. There are two possible places I would debug further.

1. Check if the Connection is working fine.
2. Check if the query execution works fine too. Remove the semicolon at the end of the query and it may work.

The logs may help you here.